# Oracle: max value of each observation, and all rows associated with max value

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that looks something like so:

```
CustomerId  TransactionID  ReceiptLine  Value
100         200               A          .90
100         200               B          .95
100         201               A          1.06
101         199               A          1.00
101         200               B          .99  
101         200               ZZ         1.02
102         300               R          1.00
102         305               R          1.00
102         305               T          1.03
...
```

And I would like to get the max TransactionID for each CustomerId and all the columns to the right of the TransactionID associated with the TransactionID.

So my hypothetical query based on the specs I've described would return:

```
CustomerId  TransactionID  ReceiptLine  Value
100         201               A          1.06
101         200               B          .99  
101         200               ZZ         1.02
102         305               R          1.00
102         305               T          1.03
```

Any thoughts or help would be greatly appreciated. I've spent a good amount of time on this and at the moment I'm to the point of returning the max TransactionID of the entire set and its corresponding CustomerID, ReceiptLines, and Values, but that's all it's returning.

Thanks

Comment: Why do transaction IDs `200` and `305` have two records in the result set?  What is the logic behind your expected output?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I need all CustomerId and (max) TransactionID corresponding ReceiptLine values and Value values.

Comment: Then why doesn't transaction `200` with receipt line `A` appear in your expected output?

Comment: Because 200 is not the max transaction for customer 100, 201 is. I need the max transaction for each customer and the two corresponding fields to the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT CustomerID, TransactionID,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY Value DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t2
    ON t1.CustomerId    = t2.CustomerId    AND
       t1.TransactionID = t2.TransactionID AND
       t2.rn = 1
ORDER BY t1.CustomerId
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Note that the demo is in SQL Server, because using Oracle on Rextester is scary, but the code should run also on Oracle without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below queries

```
SELECT CustomerId, MAX(TransactionID) AS TransactionID  ,
ReceiptLine, Value  
FROM TABLE T1 GROUP BY CustomerId, ReceiptLine, Value;
```

OR

```
SELECT T1.CustomerId, T2.TransactionID, T1.ReceiptLine, T1,Value FROM TABLE T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(TransactionID) AS TransactionID FROM TABLE GROUP BY CustomerId, ReceiptLine) T2
ON (T1.CustomerId = T2.CustomerId)
FROM TABLE T1 GROUP BY CustomerId, ReceiptLine, Value;
```

Let me know in case you face any issues